# Angularjs Test Runner - retrieving value of binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I'm a bit new to Angular JS, and I've been doing the tutorial [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08). I'm stuck on step 8, when the exercise is to write a test that tests whether the thumbnail images were displayed.

The basic idea is this. We have a JSON file called `phones/nexus-s.json`. In out controller:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phone = data;
  });
}]);
```

Okay, great, the phone JSON object gets added to the scope as `phone`. In our view:

```
<h1>{{phone.name}}</h1>

<p>{{phone.description}}</p>

<ul class="phone-thumbs">
  <li ng-repeat="img in phone.images">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Great, we iterate over all the phone's image urls.

Now, in the test, I want to retrieve that array of `phone.images`, look at its length, and make sure that the same number of `li` items in the rendered html. So my test is:

```
it('should display the correct thumbnails', function() {
    expect(element(".phone-thumbs li").count()).toBe(repeater('phone.thumbs').length);
});
```

The problem is, I don't think I have the `repeater('phone.thumbs').length` part right, and I can't figure out the right way to retrieve the `phone.thumbs` array, if that's even possible. Would anyone be able to tell me how to do this?

I'd love an explanation that actually explains what's going on here as well - there are a lot of Future object running around and to be honest, I'm not sure how to work with them effectively.

Answer (score 4):

```
it('should display 4 thumbnails', function() {
  var imageList = element.all(by.repeater('img in phone.images'));
  expect(imageList.count()).toBe(4);
});
```

That worked for me! I just noticed in the phone list view that the test for filtering the list had code that looked like it was supposed to accomplish the same sort of thing:

```
  var phoneList = element.all(by.repeater('phone in phones'));

  expect(phoneList.count()).toBe(20);
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked and shows what you should actually be doing.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the last answer, I tried it and it didn't work until I included '$ctrl' into it.

```
it('should display 4 thumbnails', function(){
      var imageList = element.all(by.repeater('img in $ctrl.phone.images'));
      expect(imageList.count()).toBe(4);
    });
```

Hope that helps.